# Write/Paste text into selected TextBox from Context Menu action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to figure out how i can **Write/Paste** a text into the selected `TextBox`.

What i want to achieve is pretty much that i select all or some text in the `TextBox`,
then i will *RightClick* and access the *Context Menu* to do task.

This task will pretty much just get the text and do some changes.
That much i can do, but Writing it back to the `TextBox` is the problem.

I have tried playing around with `window.getSelection()`.
But that as well as any other method i could find doesn't do much of anything.

Also tried some **Jquery** things to no avail.

As this is my first extension and i barely know **Javascript** it's no surprising though.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger paste by this code

```
document.execCommand('paste')
```

And to do so in extension you need to add "clipboardRead" permission in your manifest.json [[source]](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions).